# Twitter API for C# how to use

Tags: c#, json, twitter, json.net

How to use the Twitter api using C#. I am not able to get any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

You can us JsonConvert.Deserialize(string json) to deserialize a string to a class type.

```
MyType x = JsonCOnvert.Deserialize<MyType>(someJsonString);
```

Or if there isn't a type, you can convert it to a JObject and dynamically pull the properties:

```
JObject x = JObject.Parse(someJsonString);
dynamic json = x;
string url = json.city;
```

Comment: Here, what is MyType.

Comment: JObject x = JObject.Parse(someJsonString);
dynamic json = x;
string url = json.city;    the url is empty string